# CM_Get_DevNode_Property_Keys Is there a way to get names of the keys

Tags: c++, delphi, setupapi

I am able to get the property keys (DEVPROPKEY) of a devnode. However I did not found a way to get the names and/or descriptions of those keys.
It is allso possible to get the values of those property keys using CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW.

if I use a LOOP to get the keys and values I get all the info except the NAME of the key ?

EDIT
the keys are predefined in devpkey.h, like;

```
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc,             0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 2);     // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING
DEFINE_DEVPROPKEY(DEVPKEY_Device_HardwareIds,            0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0, 3);     // DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING_LIST
```

At the moment I think the only way is to compare the the keys got from the function with predefined ones.
Using Delphi I had to convert all of those keys from C++ code to Delphi code.
Still I think there should be a way to get the names via a funcion call from cfgmgr.dll or setupapi.dll ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer which I got from MSDN forum:
the names aren't stored in the sytem in a queryable manner. you have to look at the type definitions to know what they are

This means that I will have to compare the keys got from funcion with the defined ones.

I hoped that the naming and/or descriptioning were stored somewhere so I don't have to translate the naming according to the systems language. This because the the key values are returned in systems language.

Answer (score 0):

If the DEVPROPKEY is actually a PROPERTYKEY (many are), uses PSGetNameFromPropertyKey (propsys.h/propsys.dll)

Comment: It has been almost 4 years ago. devpropkey = device property key. I have been searching how to retrieve the naming, at last, after reading msdn answer(s), I gave up. See accepted answer (my own answer). Windows shows the names in systems language, so they must be stored somewhere.  but maybe not queryable ?.